# Subtract reflection of number until zero

Tags: python

Take any positive number, subtract it's reflection repeatedly until zero.
Like,

```
275-572 = -297
297-792 = -495
495-594 = -99
99-99 = 0
```

it's claimed all numbers converge to 0 this way, (except a certain number and it's multiples) so I want to test this but I'm not a programmer and haven't touched python since high school :D

all I've done so far is stealing a function from the interwebz;

```
def r(n):
    r = 0
    while n > 0:
        r *= 10
        r += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return r
```

this function returns a reflected integer. Now I need some kind of loop or recursive function of some sort but I can't come up with anything. Any help?

Comment: Btw, the number 2178 doesn't converge. Nor does MOST multiples of that number, somehow 2178*6 = 13068 does converge! I think it's because of the zero.

Anyways, any amount of 9's in between 21 and 78 also don't converge: ie.
21978
219978
2199978
219....978

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def my_func(x):
  while x != 0: # We stop when x is 0 since that is our destination
    print(f"number @ current step: {x}")
    x = abs(x - r(x)) # subtract the reflection and get rid of the negative sign (if it is negative)
```

Now, if a number does not converge to zero, `my_func` will not terminate.

The following is an improvement that detects infinite loop:

```py
# returns True if 0 is reached, False if it never reaches 0.
def my_func(x):
  cache = set()
  while x != 0: # We stop when x is 0 since that is our destination
    # print(f"number @ current step: {x}")
    x = abs(x - r(x)) # subtract the reflection and get rid of the negative sign (if it is negative)
    if x in cache:
      print(f"This number does not terminate!")
      return False
    cache.add(x)
  return True
```

After testing numbers between 0 and 999, I found no number that does not converge to 0.

Comment: Maybe add a counter or something that will `break` the loop if it didn't converge after 1000 loops or whatever is adequate.

Comment: @fsimonjetz Yes you can. I would even keep a set of previous numbers and break when an old number appears again.

Comment: Using random integers between `0` and `10000` I found some numbers that so not converge. e.g. `3608`

Comment: Try the number 2178 :) Anyways that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The [solution of MMZK1526](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73303808/1094151) can further be optimized for run-time speed at the cost of memory consumption by marking all numbers tested in a global array cache.

```py
def reflect(n):
    r = 0
    while n > 0:
        r *= 10
        r += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return r    

upper_bound = pow(10, 6) - 1

# Result cache for all tested numbers, pre-initialize the array with zeroes.
cache = [0 for i in range(upper_bound + 1)]

def test(n):
    if n == 0:
        return True
    if cache[n] == 1:
        # Early out because we already know n does converge.
        return True
    if cache[n] == 2:
        # Loop in current recursion detected, so n does not converge.
        cache[n] = 3
        return False
    if cache[n] == 3:
        # n has previously been marked as non-converging.
        cache[n] = 3
        return False
    # Temporarily mark numbers in current recursion (2)
    cache[n] = 2
    if test(abs(n - reflect(n))):
        # Mark n as converging (1).
        cache[n] = 1
        return True
    else:
        # Mark n as non-converging (3).
        cache[n] = 3
        return False
    
converging = 0
non_converging = 0
for i in range(1, upper_bound):
    if test(i):
        converging += 1
    else:
        non_converging += 1
print(f'{converging} converging and {non_converging} failing.')
```

When testing all numbers in [1..999999] I get `515419 converging and 484579 failing` in 1.328s while the non-cached approach takes 9.411s on my machine.

Comment: Can't you use a decorator to cache the numbers? I am thinking about something like `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=C)`

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but just by looking at the documentation of lru_cache, the internally used dictionary should be slightly slower than a plain array. However, the code would be much more readable indeed.

Comment: A quick test reveals that MMZK1526's solution combined with lru_cache runs in 1.392s on my machine (for n in 1..999999). So it seems negligibly slower but much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm requires to take the abs to proceed.

```
def r(n):
    r = 0
    while n > 0:
        r *= 10
        r += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return r
    
input_number = 275
max_iters = 100 # don't want to run infinitely if it does not converge
iters = 0

while( input_number != 0 and iters < max_iters ):
   
    #debug, if you wish
    print(input_number, " - ", r((input_number)))
    input_number = abs( input_number - r(input_number))
    
    iters += 1
```

Comment: The original function for reflection can also be simplyfied by: `int(str(number)[::-1])` At least with 3 or more digits I see an improvement of calculation time.

Comment: Nice visual solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looping without separate r() function

```
number = 275
break_after = 1000 # To end iteration if number doesnt become 0

while number != 0 and break_after > 0:
    reflection = int(str(number)[::-1])
    result = number - reflection
    print(f'{number} - {reflection} = {result}')
    number = abs(result)
    break_after -= 1
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution.

Comment: added if number == 2178 : break :)